# Using Percentage Slider R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I'm building a dashboard in R Shiny that has a percentage slider. I'm trying to make it a reactive function so the data table adjusts as the user moves the slider. However I have been trying to make this dynamic and although the code is not erroring, its still not working. Snippet of code below:

```
ui <- dashboardPage(

  dashboardBody(fluidRow(column(width=3, sliderInput("slider", "Threshold:", 0, 100, post = " %", 50))))

)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session){

reactive({

Value = as.character(c(input$slider))

})  

  output$Data_Table <- 

    renderTable({  

  Tbl_Data[which(Tbl_Data[,5]>input$Value),]

    })    

})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Edit - Test data below, apologies I don't know how to put it in table format:

Company Account Value   Amount  Utilisation
ABC Mr Smith     187,729,185    100,000,000 187.73%
DEF Mrs Smith    181,479,755    200,000,000 90.74%
GHI Mr Jones     97,219,166     200,000,000 48.61%
JKL Mrs Jones    91,070,604     300,000,000 30.36%

Comment: Could you include a toy data set in your example to make the problem reproducible? And remember to load the packages in the example, too.

Comment: Thanks, I have added some test data to the original post and the packages are below: library(RODBC)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(scales)
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)

Answer (score 1):

Backtracking here;

```
input$Value
```

is not defined. The `input` "list" encompasses all input controls; `Value` isn't one of them.

In your code, `Value` is a reactive. Thus to use it, call `Value()`.

Secondly, `input$slider` is itself a numeric value. I do not recall whether it is in the range 0-100 or 0.0 - 1.00, whereas you decide to convert it to a character string (`as.character(c(input$slider))`) (and why do you call that extra `c`?).

So the comparison you are doing is on ... a string. Which might or might not give unexpected results. Depends on the type of the 5th column of `Tbl_Data` - is it a character or numeric vector?

If `Tbl_Data[,5]` is numeric, your comparison can be simplified to

```
Tbl_Data[Tbl_Data[,5]>input$slider, ]
```

because `which` returns the integer positions where the argument resolves to `TRUE` - and when subsetting you directly use a logical vector of `TRUE` and `FALSE`.

Comment: Thanks for your help MrGrumble. I have changed my code but still can't get my head around this reactive part. I have, however it is still not working but I'm not sure if this is right:   reactive({

      Value() = (input$slider)

  })

Comment: No, just drop entirely your `reactive` - they are kind of like defining functions. You have to be able to refer to them (i.e. `lala <- render({ ... })`) and then to use their result, call the "function" (`renderText({ lala() })`).

Comment: Thanks MrGrumble, I think I might have to ditch the slidebar idea as I still can't get it working. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: Don't ditch the slidebar. This is basic and fundamental Shiny routines; if you cannot solve this, you'll keep stumbling. Remove the reactive on (non-empty) lines 4-6 and and update the 9th line with the example in my code. Examine it, put in a `str(Tbl_Data[Tbl_Data[,5] > input$slider, ])` before/after 9th line, and examine the output.